# dynamic allocation and deallocation

Tags: c++

I am a bit confused here, suppose i am making a container that will hold some elements and those elements can be removed.

I would have a fixed array of elements for that.

Now my question is with allocating and deallocating that array and deallocatisingle elements in it.

**1) Allocating**

```
Item* data;
Container()
{
    data = new Item[size];
}
```

Then to add I do something like that:

```
add(Item it)
{
    data[empty++] = it;
}
```

Now my question is with that allocation I have created `size` objects of `Items` then when I come in the add I add another item above, so does this means there is destruction of the old and the new take over?

Should I better use `allocater<T>` and `uninitializedfill()` as I read it allocate required memory without constructing the object.

**2) Deallocating:**

Here comes all the confusion really , on removing a single element can I use that?

```
remove(Item it)
{
    //index is item index
    delete data[index];
    //restore contiguity to array
    empty--;
}
```

can I use `delete data[index]` even if `Item` isn't a pointer? if not how then could I do this part?!

If I can then, what if `Item` was a pointer so when I delete it does it deletes the object pointed by it?

Comment: To start with, consider using `std::vector`, instead of reinventing it.

Comment: `data` is like an array of `Item`s and you are just copying `Item it` at an index `empty` in the array(and offcourse increment `empty` for the `add`).

Comment: @IgorR. well I am afraid I am implementing a custom circular queue and I need to know how to do it.

Comment: @Doggynub What you need is to construct and destroy individual items in your data. You can do that, allocate a char array, then use 'placement new' to construct and to destroy just call the destructor explicitly.

Comment: ok, circualr queue, always fun. With a queue, you will have a bunch of allocated space, and you will have indices that tell you where the head and tail are, and thus which elements are valid. If you are only dealing with head and tails, then you "add" much like above, with an assignment to the target location, and "delete" merely by adjusting the head/tail to exclude the removed element.

Comment: so no need for delete then just adjust counters, it seems I got confused I donno why i used delete on array elements when it is already fixed size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you allocate a fixed-length array with

```
data = new Item[size];
```

you have allocated all `size` elements of the array at once, in a contiguous block of memory. You do not allocate individual elements in the array, and you cannot deallocate individual elements with `delete data[index]` -- you can only deallocate the entire array with `delete[] data` when you are done.

If you anticipate needing to add and remove elements at the end of the array, I recommend using [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) instead. If you expect to add and remove elements anywhere in the array, [std::list](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/) probably makes more sense.

Comment: thats "delete[] data", not "delete data"

Answer (score 0):

```
data = new Item[size];
```

This creates an array of Items of size length, and return a poitner to them. Those itemswill be in indexes 0..(size-1) inclusive.

```
data[empty++] = it;
```

Assuming empty is < size, this will bash one of your items over the head, repalcing it with the Item passed into add(). If empty >= size than bad things will happen.

```
delete data[index];
```

This is not legal code. You are stuck with all (size) Items until you want to delete the lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
std::vector<Item> data(N);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to decide if `Item`s are *values* or *referred objects*. In fact allocation and deallocation look incoherent:

`new Item[size]` actually creates size `Item`s (that start to exist all together) and `data[i] = item` copies the lone `item` intio the `i`th `Item` addressed by `data` (replacing its internal value). In this way you are not "inserting" anything. the `empty` index (what a bad name...) just defines what to replace.

`delete data[index]` cannot work, because `data[index]` is not a pointer (its an `Item` itself).
The pair with `data = new Item[x]` is `delete[] data` that deletes all them together as together thay have been created.

Inserting and removing an item inside a block of Items of a given predefined size is ... nonsense (if you can do the the size is not predefined).

You have to consider reallocating the array, copy, and shifting elements. But this is nothing more than re-implementing `std::vector`.